# Docker complains that bind source path doesn't exist, but it DOES

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to start a mysql container with a host directory mounted. I'm running a single-node swarm in Docker for AWS. But I can't mount a directory...

This is the section of the docker-compose file I'm using:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql-custom
    volumes:
        - /mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
```

And this is the launch command I'm trying:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stack12
```

When I launch however, docker swarm rejects the image, saying "invalid mount config for type \"bind\": bind source path does not exist". However, /mysql **is** a valid directory, I can cd to it and everything, so why is docker saying it does not exist?

Comment: Did you tried to remove the **/** at the beginning?

Comment: @FrankNoel I'm trying to mount a folder, not use a docker volume

Comment: Please edit the question to add: Docker version, host OS, how Docker was installed, and what commands are producing the error.

Comment: You're talking about swarm: is the folder available on any node of your cluster? Or are-you using affinity constraint?

Comment: @AndyShinn edited

Comment: @zigarn it's a single node cluster and the folder is available on that node

Comment: ERROR: for jenkinsdocker_master_1  Cannot create container for service master: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist ... How could someone possibly not display what path Compose expects to see is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you are trying, `mysql` needs to be in **root** directory. You can try this

```
mysql:
    image: mysql-custom
    volumes:
        - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
```

Notice the `.` before `mysql`. And directory structure for this can be:

```
.
|__docker-compose.yml
|__mysql
   |__(Your content)
   |__(some more files)
```

Comment: Nope, adding the "." did not change anything.

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure! I still have doubts regarding the exact location of `mysql` directory which this compose file is trying to mount

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue due to permissions. I recommend you make a test where you grant 777 to /mysql to see if it works -> then tweak the permissions to match your security requirements

Answer (score 0):

> when using host docker volumes you need check directory permissions and if its root you must exec to container and fix the issue using chown command
> in other hand you can use below config that work fine for me

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql-custom
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
```

Comment: The question is about mounting a folder, not a docker volume.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming /mysql/ is a directory that exists at the root of your local machine.

try changing your docker-compose file as follows:

```
volumes:
    - /mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
```

Notice the trailing / that tells docker you're referring to directory /mysql/ and not file /mysql that exists at the root of the disk